# Bad MIME type in connection with Spring Security

Tags: spring, angular, browser, mime-types

How can I prevent my application from this type of errors:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8091/inline.f65dd8c6e3cb256986d2.bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

It's a `Spring Boot` app with `Angular 4` and when I run first page it throws those errors.

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0myo.png)

I think it could have connection with `Spring Security` becuase when I added:

```
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/").permitAll();
```

It started throwing errors, but I really need this piece of code. The whole method looks:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/static/**/*", "/", "/api/auth").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/").permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are extending your security configuration class from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` then you could make use of overriding `protected void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/inline.**") // or better ending with ".{js,html}" or something
        .antMatchers("/resources/static/**/*");      
}
```

This would allow all requests starting with `/inline.` and `/resources/static/...`.

Comment: Ok thanks, it removes all errors by changing my code into `@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/**.js") // or better ending with ".{js,html}" or something
                .antMatchers("/**.css"); // or better ending with ".{js,html}" or something
    }` but now I have errors like:

Comment: like: `:8091/#/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8091/glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.woff2
:8091/#/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
:8091/#/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8091/glyphicons-halflings-regular.fa2772327f55d8198301.woff
:8091/#/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
:8091/#/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8091/glyphicons-halflings-regular.e18bbf611f2a2e43afc0.ttf
:8091/#/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag`

Comment: You can add an antMatcher for that as well. Just add `.antMatchers("glyphicons-halflings-regular.**.ttf")` to your antMatchers chain. I think you got the idea.